# d=2 O(3) sigma model becomes "conformal antiferromagnet"

Tags: quantum-field-theory, conformal-field-theory, topological-field-theory

In Advanced topic in quantum field theory / M. Shifman on page 251 the author discusses the fact that the theta term is topological and does not affect the equations of motion. Then he said:

> "In particular, at $\theta=\pi$ the O(3) sigma model becomes conformal
>   and describes a ferromagnet rather than antiferromagnet.
>   Unfortunately, I cannot dwell on the aspect in this text"

Where he refers to the term $\frac{\theta}{8\pi}S^{a}(\partial_{\mu}S^{b})(\partial_{\nu}S^{c})\varepsilon^{\mu\nu}\varepsilon_{abc}$.

I would like to see here more details about this point. Is it a uniqe phenomena for $\theta=\pi$?